# MVC View Shows Project and Model name

Tags: model-view-controller

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhpU0.png) This the Out of the program on browser.

MVC Application When Executed from Development Environment Project and the Model name is translated on the web page as a string. Can Anyone Please help me to Resolve Same

```
     @Model HWAMCCallReg.Models.DownCall()

        <link rel="stylesheet" 
                      href="@Url.Content("~/Contents/StyleSheet.css")" />

         <link rel="stylesheet"                                            
                 href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-
                ui.css">
           <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
            <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

         <script type="text/javascript">
              $(function () {
                    // $("input[type=text]").first().focus();
                       $("#Caller").focus();
                    });
           </script>


              <div class="deContainer">    

                <div class="moduletitle">
                         Add DownCall
                 </div>

               <div class="decontrolsContainer">

                  @Using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "DownCall", 
                         FormMethod.Post))

                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                      @Html.ValidationSummary(True)


            @<table class="degrid">
               <tbody>

                   <tr>
                        <td class="callno">
                            <strong>Last DownCall No : @TempData("CallNo") 
                           </strong>
                      </td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                      <td>
                         <label class="caption"> Caller</label>
                      </td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                      <td>
                          @Html.TextBox("Caller", Model.Caller, New With 
                            {.class = "textbox", .tabindex = 1, .maxlength = 
                                  60})
                            @Html.ValidationMessage("Caller")
                      </td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                      <td style="padding-top:5px;">
                          <label class="caption"> System No.</label>
                      </td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                       <td>
                          @Html.DropDownList("SystemID", New 
                             SelectList(ViewBag.SystemNo, "Value", "Text", 
                              Model.SystemID), New With {.class = "cbo", 
                               .tabindex = 2})
                          @Html.ValidationMessage("SystemID")
                      </td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                      <td style="padding-top:5px;">
                          <label class="caption">Problem Reported</label>
                      </td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                     <td>
                            @Html.TextArea("ProblemReported", 
                               Model.ProblemReported.ToString, New With 
                                 {.class = "mtextbox", .tabindex = 3, 
                                  .maxlength = 600})
                             @Html.ValidationMessage("ProblemReported")
                      </td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>

                  @<div style="text-align:center;padding-top:10px; ">
                     <input id="btnSave" type="submit" value="Save" 
                      name="btnSave" class="button" />
                     </div>
             End Using
         </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Can you post your View Code?

Comment: Code added to Orginal Post. Can you please help me Out on this

Comment: You shouldn't mention your model type as "@Model HWAMCCallReg.Models.DownCall()" instead mention your model name "@model HWAMCCallReg.Models.DownCall"

Comment: I have Removed () from Model name But Still, it's not working. Output on Browser Shows        HWAMCCallReg.DownCallHWAMCCallReg.Models.DownCall

Comment: Not only () but Model m is also small.. Have you done that? See the later code on the previous comment

Comment: Thanks for Quick Reply. I have Some Same too.                             
@model HWAMCCallReg.Models.DownCall. But Same Problem

Comment: Can you also add your output you are getting in this question?

Comment: Done. Can you please Check